# Get values from non spatial table in geopackage via Python to compalist

Tags: python, geopackage

I need to get values from non spatial table in geopackage via Python. Do You have any ideas how to get this?
I'm trying get this using `spatialite3` library and simple string select query but I have receive error message "`there is no table_name in database`"
When I'm trying get this from qgis layer list I can't find appropriate way to do this. I'm trying this:

```
database = r'path_to_my_geopackage.gpkg'
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()

uri.setDatabase(database)
schema = ''
table = 'tablename'
geomColumn = ''

content = uri.setDataSource(schema,table,geomColumn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read tables from a Geopackage using the `QgsVectorLayer` interface instead of the database interface. Construct a path with a `layername` option:

```
contacts = QgsVectorLayer("test.gpkg|layername=contacts","contacts","ogr")
contacts.isValid()
#  True
```

And just to check its read the right table:

```
[f.name() for f in contacts.fields()]
# ['contact_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']
```

Then use the usual QGIS operations on attribute tables to get the values you want. Each row is a "feature", but with no geometry.

Comment: how can we make this happen in a python script outside of QGIS?

Comment: @NikhilVJ you mean using non-QGIS python libs, like fiona and shapely? That's a new question - see if you can find out yourself and then ask it as a new question on here.